# Error while declaration of ‘wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE’

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have started developing with wxWidget C++ GUI library In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have downloaded and installed all the required library but while compiling the hello world program I am getting the error as

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/wx.h:25:0,
             from wx.cpp:3:
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/event.h:96:5: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘wxEventTableEntry’
 wxEventTableEntry(type, winid, idLast, fn, obj)

.....
```

Class Declaration

```
class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
 public:
  MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
 private:
  void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
  void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
  void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
  wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE(MyFram, wxFrame);
};
```

Data Table Declaration

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
   EVT_MENU(ID_Hello,   MyFrame::OnHello)
   EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT,  MyFrame::OnExit)
   EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, MyFrame::OnAbout)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

Compilation command

> g++ wx.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags` `wx-config --libs`

How to solve this issue or How to use the event Data Table?

**Edit:**

Headers

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
   #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE(MyFram, wxFrame);
```

is incorrect. It should be:

```
wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
```

(it doesn't take any arguments).

You should be getting an error about that just before the error you mentioned in the question.

Because of the extra arguments, the macro is not expanded during the preprocessing phase. Later on during compilation, the compiler assumes you want to declare a member function and that's where your error comes from.

Comment: yes this solved the problem but I also got to remove wx from starting points of all the macros. What might be the problem?

Comment: @ali786 See the comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved By Correcting the following things.

1> Followed the answer of @bogdan

2> Removed wx from starting of all the macros.

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
  EVT_MENU(ID_Hello,   MyFrame::OnHello)
  EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT,  MyFrame::OnExit)
  EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, MyFrame::OnAbout)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

Comment: For those three macros that you changed, the versions without a `wx` prefix are considered deprecated and kept for backward compatibility, so normally you should use the `wx`-prefixed macros when available. `BEGIN / END _EVENT_TABLE()`  in particular are identical to their `wx` counterparts. `IMPLEMENT_APP()` doesn't require a `;` at the end, while the `wx` one does. These are the only differences. Why did you have to remove the `wx` prefix?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you didn't even get the definition of the macro into the program. Were the program headers and libraries linked and included correctly?

Comment: Thanks, but I have added the headers which I am using right now, Do i need to include any other?

Comment: Okay, did you compile the library itself?

Comment: I didn't and I think I don't need to compile the library I have executed an another sample program which is running fine .